# Java UML Automated generation for NetBeans 7.0

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, code-generation

I need to make UML diagrams of my project. How could I do it in NetBeans 7.0?
The program or plugin has to do it automatically.

Comment: Generating UML diagrams is contraproductive.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926197/free-uml-tool-java-to-uml-netbeans

Comment: @GabrielŠčerbák Why is generating UML diagrams not productive?

Answer (score 1):

Search the plugin in [netbeans plugin page](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/) with name is **UML**. You can find some plugins.

Also look this article, [Generating UML from netbeans.](http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked this http://netbeans.org/features/uml/?