# Reverse engineer Java classes to UML

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java UML Automated generation for netBeans 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038815/java-uml-automated-generation-for-netbeans-7-0)

I'm looking to produce UML classes from the Java code I have written. I have looked into ArgoUML but it didn't create it correctly.

I've read about plugins but they all seem to be for Eclipse. I'm using NetBeans v7.0

Comment: Why not download Eclipse? I think it is a very good IDE.

Comment: @11684 - I couldn't agree more. But I've worked fourth months on this project and I wouldn't want to mess it up by moving to Eclipse. What's Eclipse like for GUI building?

Comment: @jschoen - The suggested options on that topic don't support NetBeans V7 onwards.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926197/free-uml-tool-java-to-uml-netbeans or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687323/from-java-code-to-uml-diagram. Basically the situation is Netbeans dropped support for UML a while back (I think around 6.5) and there really has not been anything I have seen since then. I think your best bet is going to be a separate app outside of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

this might be the plugin you are looking for ? 
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/1801/netbeans-uml

Answer (score 0):

I use the eclipse plugin of  [Visual paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/), but I believe there is also a netbeans version. Writing your entire code to UML is a matter of clicking once and gets it done pretty solid. I think it requires a license though, but maybe there's a free trial.